# How do I disable the Google Translation bar when using iPhone?

Tags: ios, google-chrome

Some websites offer the Google Translation Bar hard-coded into their pages so when I visit those this bar appears on top. Like in this example:

[image: Google Translation Bar Example]

The problem with this bar however is, is that it's not scrollable. So when viewing the page on an iPhone, I can't get to the Options button of it at the far right. So I can't select Options to disable Google Translate for this website.

In Chrome you can go to Settings to turn Google Translate off for all websites. But in Safari for iPhone you can't do that. And I can't swipe the bar or something like that to get to all options. So how am I supposed to disable that translation bar when I can't get to it?

Answer (score 1):

Using IOS, open google homepage. Tap on 3 buttons tab in upper right. Tap Settings, then tap Content Settings. Slide bar left to turn off function.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

Using your iOS device, open the Settings app. Scroll down and select Safari, scroll down and select Advanced, then select Website Data.

Search for "translate" or "google". For each item you want to remove, swipe left to reveal the "Delete" button.

Delete all items related to Google Translate, and retry a site know to display the translate bar.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This question was asked many years ago so the process to do those steps might be different.  It would help if you [edit] your answer to include the OS version that you're referencing. - From Review

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me :

If you are not able to close the bar, rotate your iphone sideway and then you will be able to see the entire bar (Make sure your rotation is not locked)